# dynamic sort for linq expression function

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on an existing project that uses asp.net webapi,I am new to Linq and all the team that wrote the project code have gone.

I have a funtion in a web api controlller like that:

```
public IQueryable<AccessTypeDTO> GetAccessTypes(int pageIndex = 1, int pageSize = 25)
{
    var model = db.AccessTypes.AsQueryable();
    return model.Select(AccessTypeDTO.SELECT).Take(pageSize);
}
```

The `AccessTypeDTO` our view model and we have the domain model is EF based

The `AccessType` DM is as following:

```
 public partial class AccessType
 {
     public int AccessTypeID { get; set; }
     public string AccessTypeName { get; set; }
 }
```

The mapping and getting of data for `AccessTypeDTO` VM as following

```
public class AccessTypeDTO
{
    public int AccessTypeID { get; set; }
    public string AccessTypeName { get; set; }

    public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<AccessType, AccessTypeDTO>> SELECT =
            x => new AccessTypeDTO
            {
                AccessTypeID = x.AccessTypeID,
                AccessTypeName = x.AccessTypeName
            };
}
```

My new task to implement the paging and order for the results, so my web API function should be as follows:

```
public IQueryable<AccessTypeDTO> GetAccessTypes(int pageIndex = 1, int pageSize = 25, string orderBy = "AccessTypeID")
{
    var collection= db.AccessTypes.AsQueryable();

    return collection.Select(AccessTypeDTO.SELECT).Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
}
```

The main issue is  in the function I am building that the Skip function requires the collection "collection" to be sorted before skip. 
So How can I sort this collection?
Please note that  I have more than one hundred controller to be updated and have paging and sorting like this way and I have no time to write a service for each controller and write switch for each column , to do the sorting

Answer (score 0):

something like this may help you:

```
 public static class MyLinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<AccessTypeDto> GetPage(this IQueryable<AccessType> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        return source.Select(x => new AccessTypeDto()
        {
            AccessTypeID = x.AccessTypeID,
            AccessTypeName = x.AccessTypeName
        }).OrderBy(x => x.AccessTypeID).Skip(pageIndex*pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }
}
```

and you can use it on your collection like this:

```
collection.GetPage(1,25);
```

hope it will help!

Edit:

you can change your method like this:

```
 public static IQueryable<AccessTypeDto> GetPage(this IQueryable<AccessType> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, Expression<Func<AccessTypeDto,object>>  predicate)
    {
        return source.Select(x => new AccessTypeDto()
        {
            AccessTypeID = x.AccessTypeID,
            AccessTypeName = x.AccessTypeName
        }).OrderBy(predicate).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }
```

and then you can call the method, like this:

```
collection.GetPage(1,25,x=>x.AccessTypeId);
```

or

```
collection.GetPage(0,25,x=>x.AccessTypeId);
```

Regarding (pageIndex-1) - I preffer to start from pageIndex=0, and in this way I do not need to have -1.

Comment: thanks dear . I think the skip should be : .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

How Can I make the order by field dynamic?